# Get offset from element other than parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

Using `element.offset().left` gets you the element's offset position from its parent. Is there any way to get the offset position from another element? For example, here's my html:

```
<div id="tile_id_579" class="product_tile">  
<div class="selectContainer">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>        
                <div id="select-undefined" class="tzSelect">
                    <div id="options-undefined" class="tzOptions" style="max-height: 500px; width: 250px; display: none; min-width: 118px;">
                        <ul class="dropDown" id="dropdown-undefined">
                            <li><div class="header">Hand-Tossed Style Pizza</div>
                                <div class="subheader">The crowd-pleasing pizza that everyone can agree on.</div>
                                <div class="optkey">0</div>
                            </li>
                            <li><div class="header">Pan Pizza</div>
                                <div class="subheader">Our Pan Pizza is America's favorite!</div>
                                <div class="optkey">1</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

It's generated from a database. Using `offset().left` gets me the offset from the `#selecct-undefined` div, but I need to get how far the `#options-undefined` div is from the `.selectContainer` div. Is this possible?

**EDIT TO ADD**

Tried both of these, and both return the same thing: top: 381, left: 0. But left is NOT 0 in relation to the document; it can't be.

```
var tip = $('#tile_id_579 #options-undefined .header');
tip.first().position();
```

and

```
var tip = $('#tile_id_579 #options-undefined .header');
tip.first().offset();
```

How is it possible that left is 0 for both when this is where the div is? Doesn't 0 left imply that it's all the way at the left of the browser window?

[image]

Comment: [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is relative to the document, [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is relative to the offset parent.

Comment: I've tried both, and they both return the same values. I'm not sure how this is possible when the parent isn't the document itself... Adding example to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Since your element is indeed within that parent you specified you can use .position() instead of .offset(). But if .selectContainer is not the closest relative parent you will need to get the position of both your element and that "other" element and calculate the difference.

```
var myPos = $('#options-undefined').offset();
var otherPos = $('#options-undefined').closest('.selectContainer').offset();//if #options-undefined wasn't a child of .selectContainer you would do $('.selectContainer').offset();

var _offset = {
    top: otherPos.top - myPos.top,
    left: otherPos.left - myPos.left
}
```